# where to put maven parametrized junit input xml files

Tags: java, maven-2, junit

I have parametrized junit test that reads from several XML input files.  In the code, I have it like this:

```
@Parameters
public static Collection<Object[]> getFiles() {
  Collection<Object[]> params = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
  for (File f : new File(".").listFiles(new someInputFileFilter())) {
    Object[] arr = new Object[] { f };
    params.add(arr);
  }
  return params;
}
```

What is the recommended way to include possibly hundreds of these XML input files under Maven?  Where do I put it? And what changes I need to make to POM and source code above to read these XML files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the files somewhere in `src/test/resources`, say `src/test/resources/xmlfiles`; this will cause Maven to automatically mirror these into `target/test-classes`.  Then you can consume them as [described by James Lorenzen](http://jlorenzen.blogspot.com/2007/06/proper-way-to-access-file-resources-in.html):

```
URL path = this.getClass().getResource("/xmlfiles");
File xmlfileDir = new File(url.getFile());
for (File f : xmlfileDir.listFiles(new ...Filter())) {
    ....
}
```

No POM changes should be necessary.

Comment: is there alternative to  this.getClass().getResource("/xmlfiles");  ?  I'm using parameterized junit with static method.

Comment: @bob try `MyTestClass.class.getResource("/xmlfiles")`